# How to use X509Extension value?

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle

1)

```
byte[] crldpExt = cert.getExtensionValue(X509Extensions.CRLDistributionPoints.getId());
String skiOid = X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.getId();
```

`CRLDistributionPoints` and `AuthorityKeyIdentifier` are deprecated in Bouncy Castle 1.46. According to the GrepCode `X509Extension` value should be used at this place. But i am not getting "How to use".

2) `V3TBSCertificateGenerator.setSubject(x500Name);`

According to the new document, It should work. But it is giving the error that it is not applicable for argument (`X500Name`) change it to (`X509Name`). But `X509Name` is deprecated.

3)

```
X509Principal principal = PrincipalUtil.getSubjectX509Principal(x509cert);
Vector <?> values = principal.getValues(X509Name.CN);
if (cn != null)
    certificate.setCn(cn.get(0).toString());
```

As `X509Name` is deprecated. That is why i changed this to following :

```
X500Name x500name = new JcaX509CertificateHolder(x509cert).getSubject();
RDN[] cn = null;
cn = x500name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN);
if (cn != null)
    certificate.setCn(cn.toString());
```

Is it correct. Please let me know if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `CRLDistributionPoints` and `AuthorityKeyIdentifier` using [X509Extension](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/X509Extension.html) available in bouncycastle 1.46

```
cert.getExtensionValue(X509Extension.cRLDistributionPoints.getId());
String skiOid = X509Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier.getId();
```

2) Use `V3TBSCertificateGenerator.setSubject(x500Name);` It is available and not deprecated in 1.46. See [V3TBSCertificateGenerator](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/V3TBSCertificateGenerator.html). Ensure you have the correct import for x500Name `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name`

3) Alternatively you can use `X500Name.getInstance()`

```
X500Name x500name = X500Name.getInstance(x509cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getEncoded());
RDN cn = x500name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN)[0];
String cnAsString = IETFUtils.valueToString(cn.getFirst().getValue());
```

Comment: 1) Actually CRLDistributionPoints and AuthorityKeyIdentifier both are deprecated. I need Some alternative for that.        org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier
          use X509Extension value.

Comment: 2) It is available. X509Name is deprecated. But when i am using this, I am getting the error-like i can not use x500Name as argument.

Comment: 1) Please read the answer. I am using `X509Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier` and not `X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdenti‌​fier`

Comment: I am really sorry. But X509Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier is not available in 1.46.

Comment: Please, check the links I've provided of bouncycastle 1.46. Both `X509Extension` and `V3TBSCertificateGenerator.setSubject(x500Name)` are available in that version and match with the code i have posted in the answer. Ensure you have the 1.46 bouncycastle jars in your project and no other version

Comment: Hi @AartiJangid, did you check the answer?

Comment: yes i checked the answer.  But now i am upgrading the bouncycastle itself :)

Comment: Ah, good option, since version 1.46 is a little old. bouncycastle usually changes the interface between versions so it is convenient to start from the last. Consider also to mark the answer as accepted if it fits your question or upvote if it has been of help